# Non-recursive split iteration of array with tbb::paralllel_for

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, tbb

I'm trying to perform a computation over a one-dimensional array `A[]` using Intel's TBBs. The problem is that, by default, an algorithm like `tbb::parallel_for` would cut the array in half recursively, sending each chunk to the task pool for the threads to steal.

However, I want all threads to "scan" the array in a linear way. For example, using 4 threads have them compute, in parallel, first `A[0], A[1], A[2]` and `A[3]` in any order. And then, compute the set `A[4], A[5], A[6]` and `A[7]`, in any order.

Right now, `parallel_for`, after a couple of recursive splits would compute first `A[0], A[2], A[4]` and `A[6]` respectively. And then, `A[1], A[3], A[5]` and `A[7]` (or something similar).

I'm using C++14 and Intel's [Threading Building Blocks](https://software.intel.com/en-us/tbb-documentation). Algorithms like `parallel_reduce` or `parallel_scan` operate in a similar fashion, regarding the splitting of the iteration space, so they haven't been much of a help.

My guess is that I have do define my own iteration space object, but I can't figure out how exactly. The [docs](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506065) give this definition:

```cpp
class R {
    // True if range is empty
    bool empty() const;
    // True if range can be split into non-empty subranges
    bool is_divisible() const;
    // Splits r into subranges r and *this
    R( R& r, split );
    // Splits r into subranges r and *this in proportion p
    R( R& r, proportional_split p );
    // Allows usage of proportional splitting constructor
    static const bool is_splittable_in_proportion = true;
    ...
};
```

It all boils down to this code:

```cpp
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <tbb/parallel_for.h>
#include <tbb/task_scheduler_init.h>

std::mutex cout_mutex;

int main()
{
    auto N = 8;

    tbb::task_scheduler_init init(4);

    tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, N),
        [&](const tbb::blocked_range<int>& r)
        {
            for (int j = r.begin(); j < r.end(); ++j) {
                // Compute A[j]
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
                cout_mutex.lock();
                std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id()<< ", " << j << std::endl;
                cout_mutex.unlock();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

The above code gives:

```
140455557347136, 0
140455526110976, 4
140455521912576, 2
140455530309376, 6
140455526110976, 5
140455557347136, 1
140455521912576, 3
140455530309376, 7
```

but I wanted something like:

```
140455557347136, 0
140455526110976, 1
140455521912576, 2
140455530309376, 3
140455526110976, 5
140455557347136, 4
140455521912576, 6
140455530309376, 7
```

Any suggestions on the iteration object or is there a better solution?

Comment: If you need guaranteed sequential execution, don't use threads.

Comment: I don't want guaranteed sequential execution, I want to compute _in parallel_ the first N elements of the array (in any order), then the second batch of N elements (in any order) etc. N is the number of threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using an external atomic, e.g. ( `// !!!` marks changed lines)

```
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <tbb/parallel_for.h>
#include <tbb/task_scheduler_init.h>

#include <atomic>                                 // !!!

std::mutex cout_mutex;

int main()
{
    auto N = 8;

    tbb::task_scheduler_init init(4);

    std::atomic<int> monotonic_begin{0};           // !!!

    tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, N),
        [&](const tbb::blocked_range<int>& r)
        {
            int s = static_cast<int>(r.size());    // !!!
            int b = monotonic_begin.fetch_add(s);  // !!!
            int e = b + s;                         // !!!
            for (int j = b; j < e; ++j) {          // !!!       
                // Compute A[j]
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
                cout_mutex.lock();
                std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << ", " << j << std::endl;
                cout_mutex.unlock();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

The approach gives:

```
15084, 0
15040, 3
12400, 2
11308, 1
15084, 4
15040, 5
12400, 6
11308, 7
```

Why it is important to have monotonic behavior? You may want to consider `parallel_pipeline` or flow graph to specify calculation dependencies.

Comment: I wanted to compute a memoization table, where having computed the first elements will save you time for the last. That's why I wanted monotonic behavior. Also, pipelines and flow graphs are definitely worth a try :)

Comment: It looks like that you can use `concurrent_hash_map` or `concurrent_unordered_map` to implement memorization. Why the order is important?